# Setting a custom loss for sklearn gradient boosting classfier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Sklearn gradient boosting classifier accepts deviance and exponential loss, as detailed [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#gradient-boosting) and [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html). But, can we pass a custom loss instead of its predefined loss ('deviance' or 'exponential' loss).

---

**Similar questions on stackoverflow and why they are not answering my question:**

I already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55076833/adjust-custom-loss-function-for-gradient-boosting-classification), which looks most relevant. **But** it does not cover my question at all, since it **does not discuss how could one pass the custom loss to GradientBoostingClassifier**.

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720878/customize-loss-function-sklearn) looks relevant, **but** the answer does not explain once you define a class (as described in the answer), how do you pass this as an argument to the GradientBoostingClassifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do so, you should create a subclass of "[BaseGradientBoosting](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/_gb.py#L1269)" and a subclass of both the first subclass and GradientBoostingClassifier (in the classification case) classes. Inside first class you should pass the name of the custom loss function in the `super().__init__`, and inside the second subclass you can pass the name of your custom loss function as a `_SUPPORTED_LOSS`.

Besides, to turn off the `ValueError` of `_check_params` in SKlearn gradient boosting, you have to override this function, or consider an exception for this function.

For example:

```
class my_base_gradient_boost(BaseGradientBoosting, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, *args):
       super().__init__(loss='my_custom_loss', *other_args)

    def _check_params(self):
      try:
        super()._check_params()
      except ValueError as e:
        if str(e) == "Loss 'my_costum_loss' not supported. ":
            self.loss_ = self.my_costum_loss
        else:
            raise

class my_classifier(my_base_gradient_boost, GradientBoostingClassifier):

    _SUPPORTED_LOSS = ('my_costum_loss')

    @_deprecate_positional_args           
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
```

Please keep in mind that *args are all the arguments of BaseGradientBoosting.

Well, that's a lot of work, but I could not find any better solution to do so. I hope this helps.

P.S. by the way, you are right, the mentioned links don't answer your question.