# Sklearn HistGradientBoostingClassifier with custom loss

Tags: scikit-learn, loss-function

I am trying to implement a custom_loss for HistGradientBoostingClassifier (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier.html)

This link looks relevant [Setting a custom loss for sklearn gradient boosting classfier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682250/setting-a-custom-loss-for-sklearn-gradient-boosting-classfier) , but it creates subclass BaseGradientBoosting, and not the BaseHistGradientBoosting.

Before attempting to do the custom loss, I decided to try out the BCE_loss, and verify if it works:

```
"""


from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

import numpy as np
from scipy.special import expit, logsumexp, xlogy
from sklearn.ensemble._hist_gradient_boosting.common import Y_DTYPE
from sklearn.ensemble._hist_gradient_boosting.common import G_H_DTYPE
from sklearn.utils.stats import _weighted_percentile
from sklearn._loss.loss import BaseLoss
from sklearn._loss.link import (
    IdentityLink,
    Interval,
    LogitLink,
    LogLink,
    MultinomialLogit,
)


import torch

class custom_loss:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def loss(self,
            y_true,
            raw_prediction,
            sample_weight=None,
            loss_out=None,
            n_threads=1):
        
        y_true = np.array(y_true)
        raw_prediction = np.array(raw_prediction)

        return np.log(1 + np.exp(raw_prediction))-y_true*raw_prediction


    def loss_gradient(self,
                      y_true,
                      raw_prediction,
                      sample_weight=None,
                      loss_gradient_out=None,
                      n_threads=1):
        pass

    def gradient(self,
                 y_true,
                 raw_prediction,
                 sample_weight=None,
                 gradient_out=None,
                 n_threads=1):
        
        raw_prediction = np.array(raw_prediction)
        y_true = np.array(y_true)
        
        raw_prediction = torch.tensor(raw_prediction, requires_grad=True)
        y_true = torch.tensor(y_true)
        loss = torch.log(1 + torch.exp(raw_prediction)) - y_true * raw_prediction
        loss = torch.sum(loss)

        grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, raw_prediction, create_graph=True)[0]

        grad = grad.detach().numpy()

       # grad = [torch.autograd.grad(loss[i], raw_prediction, create_graph=True)[0][i].item()
             #   for i in range(len(raw_prediction))]
        return grad

    def gradient_hessian(self,
                         y_true,
                         raw_prediction,
                         sample_weight=None,
                         gradient_out=None,
                         hessian_out=None,
                         n_threads=1):
        
        raw_prediction = np.array(raw_prediction)
        y_true = np.array(y_true)
        
        raw_prediction = torch.tensor(raw_prediction, requires_grad=True)
        y_true = torch.tensor(y_true)
        loss = torch.log(1 + torch.exp(raw_prediction)) - y_true * raw_prediction
        loss = torch.sum(loss)
        


        grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, raw_prediction, create_graph=True)[0]

       
        hessian = np.array([torch.autograd.grad(grad[i], raw_prediction, retain_graph=True)[0][i].item()
                for i in range(len(raw_prediction))])       
       

        return grad.detach().numpy(), hessian





class BCE_loss(BaseLoss):
    """    """

    def __init__(self, sample_weight=None):
        super().__init__(
            closs=custom_loss(),
            link=LogitLink(),
            n_classes=2,
        )
        self.interval_y_true = Interval(0, 1, True, True)

    def constant_to_optimal_zero(self, y_true, sample_weight=None):
        # This is non-zero only if y_true is neither 0 nor 1.
        term = xlogy(y_true, y_true) + xlogy(1 - y_true, 1 - y_true)
        if sample_weight is not None:
            term *= sample_weight
        return term

    def predict_proba(self, raw_prediction):
        """Predict probabilities.

        Parameters
        ----------
        raw_prediction : array of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, 1)
            Raw prediction values (in link space).

        Returns
        -------
        proba : array of shape (n_samples, 2)
            Element-wise class probabilities.
        """
        # Be graceful to shape (n_samples, 1) -> (n_samples,)
        if raw_prediction.ndim == 2 and raw_prediction.shape[1] == 1:
            raw_prediction = raw_prediction.squeeze(1)
        proba = np.empty((raw_prediction.shape[0], 2), dtype=raw_prediction.dtype)
        proba[:, 1] = self.link.inverse(raw_prediction)
        proba[:, 0] = 1 - proba[:, 1]
        return proba
```

For the BCE_loss class I basically copy-pasted the HalfBinomialLoss defined here :https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/d99b728b3a7952b2111cf5e0cb5d14f92c6f3a80/sklearn/_loss/loss.py , and replaced closs=CyHalfBinomialLoss() with closs==custom_loss()

I have double checked that the custom_loss I created indeed gives me the correct gradient and hessian that I want.

```
loss = custom_loss()

ypred = np.random.rand(100)
ytrue = np.random.randint(0,2,100)


def bceloss(ytrue,ypred):
    ypred = 1/(1+np.exp(-ypred))
    return -(ytrue*np.log(ypred)+(1-ytrue)*np.log(1-ypred))

def bce_grad(ytrue,ypred):
    sigmoid = 1/(1+np.exp(-ypred))
    return (sigmoid - ytrue) 

def bce_hess(ytrue,ypred):
    ypred = 1/(1+np.exp(-ypred))
    return ypred*(1-ypred)

print(loss.loss(ytrue,ypred) - bceloss(ytrue,ypred))
print(loss.gradient(ytrue,ypred) - bce_grad(ytrue,ypred))
print(loss.gradient_hessian(ytrue,ypred)[1] - bce_hess(ytrue,ypred))
```

But the loss stays constant when I run this, and I get very bad performance:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import HistGradientBoostingClassifier

clf = HistGradientBoostingClassifier(loss = BCE_loss(), max_iter=200,
                                     verbose=1)
clf.fit(traindata, trainlabels)
predict = clf.predict_proba(testdata)[:,1]
```

From this link (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/17659) it seems like this feature is already implemented, but I haven't found any documentation on how to implement this.

Comment: The [PR adding the feature](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/16908) (mentioned in your linked Issue) gives the basic idea: you need to subclass `BaseLoss`, presumably implementing the relevant methods.  The `BaseLoss` class as well as several builtin examples are in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/_loss/loss.py (moved from that original PR), and hopefully give enough of an idea of what needs to be implemented. Note that all this is private API, so could break in future versions.

Comment: I attempted to create a loss, which is a subclass of BaseLoss, and updated the post. It runs without errors, but the loss does not change.